# splinter web error

Tags: python, web, splinter

```
from splinter import Browser                
with Browser() as browser: 
  browser.visit("http://www.google.co.uk")
  browser.fill('q', 'Testing')
  browser.find_by_name('Submit').click()
```

That code opens up Firefox and gives me an error `Url is not valid`.

Comment: What is the python version you are using?

Answer (score 0):

I do not think this is any issue with the code, rather it is the versions of Python/Splinter/Selenium/browser/[webdriver](https://sites.google.com/a/chromium.org/chromedriver/downloads) (there are a lot of components at play)

This should be working.

```
from splinter import Browser    
url = 'https://www.google.co.uk/?gws_rd=ssl'            
with Browser() as browser: 
  browser.visit(url)
  browser.fill('q', 'Testing\n')
```

If this is helpful, here are my versions:

```
Python: 3.3.5
Splinter: 0.7.2
Selenium: 2.45.0
Browser: Chrome
Webdriver: 2.25
```

If you are unsure of which versions you have of selenium and splinter, here's an easy way to check:

```
import pkg_resources
pkg_resources.get_distribution("splinter").version
>>> 0.7.2
```